# Weblogic exception: "weblogic.wsee.jaxws.client.async.AsyncTransportProvider" failed to preload on startup in Web application:

Tags: java, server, startup, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I am running an application on Oracle Weblogic server version:10.3.5

The below exception is thrown while launching the application.

I checked for weblogic.jar and weblogic.fullclient.jar files in the war file and none of these jar files are present in the deployed war file.

Thanks for the help.

The full stacktrace:

```
Sep 15, 2017 4:43:00 PM CDT Error Deployer BEA-149265 Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1505511763733' for task '1'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "weblogic.wsee.jaxws.client.async.AsyncTransportProvider" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "IFEVZWGUI".
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.InstantiationException: weblogic.wsee.jaxws.client.async.AsyncTransportProvider
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver.getSingleton(WLSInstanceResolver.java:36)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver.start(WLSInstanceResolver.java:55)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.start(WLSInstanceResolver.java:82)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube.setEndpoint(InvokerTube.java:85)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.EndpointAwareLateInitTube.postCreateEndpoint(EndpointAwareLateInitTube.java:48)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:150)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:64)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1985)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1959)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1878)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:485)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:201)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:249)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:28)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:637)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:140)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:164)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.InstantiationException: weblogic.wsee.jaxws.client.async.AsyncTransportProvider
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletInstanceResolver.create(WLSServletInstanceResolver.java:37)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver.getSingleton(WLSInstanceResolver.java:34)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver.start(WLSInstanceResolver.java:55)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.start(WLSInstanceResolver.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube.setEndpoint(InvokerTube.java:86)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.EndpointAwareLateInitTube.postCreateEndpoint(EndpointAwareLateInitTube.java:49)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: weblogic.wsee.jaxws.client.async.AsyncTransportProvider
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.injection.WSEEComponentContributor.newInstance(WSEEComponentContributor.java:54)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.injection.WSEEComponentContributor.newInstance(WSEEComponentContributor.java:42)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletInstanceResolver.create(WLSServletInstanceResolver.java:35)
    ... 52 more
'
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "weblogic.wsee.jaxws.client.async.AsyncTransportProvider" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "IFEVZWGUI".
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.InstantiationException: weblogic.wsee.jaxws.client.async.AsyncTransportProvider
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver.getSingleton(WLSInstanceResolver.java:36)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver.start(WLSInstanceResolver.java:55)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.start(WLSInstanceResolver.java:82)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube.setEndpoint(InvokerTube.java:85)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.EndpointAwareLateInitTube.postCreateEndpoint(EndpointAwareLateInitTube.java:48)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.registerEndpoint(JAXWSServlet.java:150)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.init(JAXWSServlet.java:64)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSDeployedServlet.init(JAXWSDeployedServlet.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1985)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1959)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1878)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:485)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:201)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:249)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:427)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:28)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:637)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:140)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:164)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.InstantiationException: weblogic.wsee.jaxws.client.async.AsyncTransportProvider
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletInstanceResolver.create(WLSServletInstanceResolver.java:37)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver.getSingleton(WLSInstanceResolver.java:34)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver.start(WLSInstanceResolver.java:55)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.start(WLSInstanceResolver.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube.setEndpoint(InvokerTube.java:86)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.EndpointAwareLateInitTube.postCreateEndpoint(EndpointAwareLateInitTube.java:49)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: weblogic.wsee.jaxws.client.async.AsyncTransportProvider
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.injection.WSEEComponentContributor.newInstance(WSEEComponentContributor.java:54)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.injection.WSEEComponentContributor.newInstance(WSEEComponentContributor.java:42)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletInstanceResolver.create(WLSServletInstanceResolver.java:35)
    ... 52 more
```